# Update a table using another table in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I have table t1 and t2, how can I create table t3? Basically I want to update Var2 in t1 where t1.Key=t2.Key, using the data from t2 while keeping everything else in t1 the same.

Table t1

```
Key Var1 Var2

1    A    AA
2    B    BB
3    C    CC
4    D    DD
5    E    EE
```

Table t2

```
Key Var1 Var2
3    C    XX
4    D    YY
6    F    FF
```

Table t3

```
Key Var1 Var2
1    A    AA
2    B    BB
3    C    XX
4    D    YY
5    E    EE
```

The following SAS code would simply give me errors:

```
proc sql;
update t1 
set  var2 = t2.var2
from t1
inner join t2 on 
t1.key=t2.key;
quit;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It could be done like:

```
data t1;
  input Key Var1 $ Var2 $;
  datalines;
1    A    AA
2    B    BB
3    C    CC
4    D    DD
5    E    EE
;

data t2;
  input Key Var1 $ Var2 $;
  datalines;
3    C    XX
4    D    YY
6    F    FF
;

title 'Table T1';
proc print data=t1 noobs;run;

title 'Table T2';
proc print data=t2 noobs;run;
```

Update itself:

```
proc sql;
  update t1 set var2 = (select var2 from t2 where t2.key=t1.key)
    where t1.key in(select key from t2);
quit;
```

Check:

```
title 'Updated T1';
proc print data=t1 noobs;run;
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, your code works well. However, is there any way to keep F FF from table T2 to T1? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @Jean Hu! Here is example of update with SQL. We update data in A table (master) with a update table B. We should not add record in this case. If you need to add F FF from B use full join or use merge in data step.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `update` statement in a data step. `Update` statements are very similar to `merge` statements, except that they do not replace populated values with missing values unless you specify. In addition, non-unique keys generate a warning, which is helpful for debugging.

The general syntax for updating tables and creating a new one simultaneously:

**Syntax**

```
data NewTable;
    update MasterTable
           TransactionTable;
    by key(s);
run;
```

In order to do an `update` operation with your data, you need to make sure that your two datasets are either sorted or indexed by the key variable. If it's not sorted or indexed, SAS will complain and the update will fail. In general, I just add the `index` option at the final steps that I need to do to create the master or transactional datasets. It tends to save some time because an additional sorting step is prevented.

**Step 1: Make sure Tables 1 & 2 are either indexed or sorted by key**

```
data t1(index=(key) );
    <ETL stuff>;
run;

data t2(index=(key) );
    <ETL stuff>;
run;
```

**Step 2: Create a new table, t3, by updating t1 with matching values from t2**

```
data t3(index=(key) );
   update t1(in=t1_key)  /* Same thing as SQL t1.key */
          t2(in=t2_key); /* Same thing as SQL t2.key */
   by key;

   /* This is SAS's way of specifying a left-join */
   if(t1_key);
run;
```

Though you do not specifically need the `index=` option on `t3` here, it is good practice to keep your key variable indexed or have an integrity constraint applied to it.

Comment: Very helpful Stu. Thank you so much!