# SAS EG append new data and overwrite already existing rows

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

My goal is to update this table called DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER_lib_xlsx:

Here i a sample of my data. Don't mind the cmd prompt it is only to cover sensitive data.

[image]

I then have a table with a similar structure called DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER:
[image]

But how do I append the table DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER_lib_xlsx with DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER. And if DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER_lib_xlsx contains rows with the same "approval_text" as DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER the rows in DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER_lib_xlsx gets deleted and the rows from DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER is appended.

I hope you can point me in the right direction

Comment: It looks like data from EBA DPM for supervisory reporting, perhaps liquidity templates? If so, business keys are well defined. If both files share the same structure (column and row wise), you could try what is advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35656382/10468613).

Comment: Careful about the `amount` column though, it seems character in one and numeric in the other.

Comment: @Kermit you guessed right it is used for EBA DPM liquidity templates. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it in a two-step method if your table is small.

First, create a temporary table of `DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER_lib_xlsx`  that excludes matching values of `approval_text`. This is similar to deleting matching values of `approval_text`.

```
proc sql;
    create table temp as
        select *
        from DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER_lib_xlsx 
        where approval_text NOT IN(select approval_text from DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER)
    ;
quit;
```

Then set the two tables together. This will append all the new and updated values to the original table.

```
/* Append the updated and new values */
data DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER_lib_xlsx;
    set temp
        DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER
    ;
run;
```

There are more sophisticated ways to do this if you have big data, but this is a very easy way to do updates to old data for small tables. The reason we're doing it this way is because `approval_text` is not unique. If there are a differing number of values of `approval_text`, we want to remove all of the old rows and append these new rows which could include more or fewer values.